# Why does index sometimes operate unexpectedly in reduce() method?

Tags: javascript, reduce

I'm experimenting with `.reduce()` and in the test code below I attempt to set `accumulator.key[index]` to the value 1. By using a `console.log` I can see that index is cycling correctly from 0 through 3.  However my code only sets `accumulator.key[3]` to the value 1.  The first 3 `accumulator.key[index]` it leaves as undefined.  This is totally baffling to me.  I can't see why it wouldn't set all 4 keys to 1.  Thanks for any help!

```js
"use strict";

var testArray = ['fe', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum'];
var output;
 
output = testArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
  accumulator.key = [];
  console.log(index);
  accumulator.key[index] = 1;
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output.key);
```

Comment: `accumulator.key = [];` on every step of `.reduce()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You in every iteration with this statement `accumulator.key = []` assign to the `key` property a new `[]`, which removes the previous array reference. Pass an object instead an array and define the `key` property on it as array.

```js
var testArray = ['fe', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum'];
var output;
 
output = testArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
  console.log(index);
  accumulator.key[index] = 1;
  return accumulator;
}, { key: [] });

console.log(output.key);
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct!  I neglected to see that I was resetting that each cycle.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your use case to use `.key` on an array but if that is what you decided then just don't initialise it to an array on each iteration. And if you are afraid of getting an undefined in the first iteration then use a fallback empty array.

```
  accumulator.key = (accumulator.key || []);
```

```js
"use strict";

var testArray = ['fe', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum'];
var output;
 
output = testArray.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => {
  accumulator.key = (accumulator.key || []);
  console.log(index);
  accumulator.key[index] = 1;
  return accumulator;
}, []);

console.log(output.key);
```

Comment: I never thought about a fallback.  Brilliant!